# USB hard drive appears multiple times in /media

Tags: usb, mount, hard-drive, backup, usb-drive

My 2Tb Seagate backup drive is plugged into my laptop all the time. When I first plugged it in, it appeared as one drive in `/media`. Now, when I look in `/media`, it shows 4 drives entitled "Milford", "Milford1", "Milford2", and "Milford3".

Clicking on "Milford3" leads me to my normal directory in the backup drive, but clicking on any of the others gives an error message.

Is there a way to refresh my media folder? It causes major problems when I try to direct my cloud backup client to a drive with a changing name. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

had this same problem on mint 21.1, my "solution" was...

1. physically unmount the drive(s)
2. restart (just in case)
3. launch nemo as root (could probably use terminal but im a windows pleb)
4. delete the duplicated drives in /media/... (only the duplicate ones)
   (the real drive should not be listed as it was unmounted)
5. restart again (just in case)
6. then remount the drives and the os just re-detects them and everything should work as before

the drives are duplicated progressively so technically randomdrive(0) is a fake whilst randomdrive(1 or 2 or whatever the highest number is) is the real entry, so if you are doing some other unmounting method keep that in mind.
i have no idea why this happens but this works as a temporary remedy.

Comment: This is a Ubuntu only site. Do you know for sure this non Ubuntu solution works on Ubuntu?

Comment: @David my solution is basically just 'unplug then plug in' so this would probably work on any OS, i felt a post was warranted because this question was the only post i found on my entire search for the exact problem stated, and i was initially unsure that deleting media entries wouldn't break anything but it worked for me, and seeing how mint is derivative of Ubuntu i assumed the same bugs would exist for me too.